# How to test for the difference in the statistical distribution of raster values in different zones?

Tags: raster, spatial-statistics, statistics

I have a continuous raster that has been divided in 8 zones, and I'd like to compare if the distribution of pixel values in each zone is significantly different from each other.
I thought I would use a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, but I've been advised not to.

Is there a statistical method out there that allow for the multiple comparison of non-normal distributions, without having to create a statistical model of the type Y~X?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you have been advised to not use the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test. If you put it in the context of a cumulative distribution, and not probability density, function it would likely address your question. Another option are the family of nonparametric t-tests, such as the Mann-Whitney-Wilcoxon test.

You can apply this test using the `wilcox.test` function in R however, the assumption of the statistic is that the samples come from a distinct population and do not affect each other. Violation of this assumption would be highly dependent on your zones.

Comment: Thanks Jeffrey. This main assumption seems by essence impossible to meet for spatial data...although the zones have been defined based on their hydrologic behavior and so "hydrologically" disconnected. Therefore, I think they may be considered as independent.